# injected db credentials change when I deploy new app version to cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, cloud-foundry

I deploy a web app to a local cloudfoundry environment. As a database service for my DEV environment I have chosen a Marketplace service `google-cloudsql-postgres` with the plan `postgres-db-f1-micro`. Using the Web UI I created an instance with the name `myapp-test-database` and mentioned it in the CF Manifest:

```
applications:
- name: myapp-test
  services:
   - myapp-test-database
```

At first, all is fine. I can even redeploy the existing artifact. However, when I build a new version of my app and push it to CF, the injected credentials are updated and the app can no longer access the tables:

```
PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for table
```

The tables are still there, but they're owned by the previous user. They were automatically created by the ORM in the `public` schema.

While the `-OLD` application still exists I can retrieve the old username/password from the CF Web UI or `$VCAP_SERVICES` and drop the tables.

Is this all because of Rolling App Deployments? But then there should be a lot of complaints.

Comment: If you are strictly doing a `cf push` (or restart/restage), the broker isn't involved (Cloud Controller doesn't talk to it) so if something were changing with your credentials it would be happening outside of what is happening with CF. The only action through `cf` that can modify your credentials is doing an `unbind` / `bind`. Many, but not all, service brokers will throw away credentials on `unbind` and provide new, unique credentials for a `bind`.

Comment: `While the -OLD application still exists` -> sounds like you're not using the rolling deployment feature in `cf7`. That feature does not use two apps, it is using different primitives in CF. If you have two different apps in CF (i.e. `cf apps` shows two), you'd have to have two separate bindings, which means two separate credentials. If you need both apps to have the same creds, you can use a service key instead. Service keys are like bindings but not associated with an app. You can then pass the service key creds in via a user provided service or env variables.

Comment: @DanielMikusa yes, looks like the build script we use emulates rolling deploy. Your advice to use a service key helped! And I'm really disappointed that cf can't inject service key credentials to `$VCAP_SERVICES` like it does for bound services

Comment: That's not really the intent of a service key. Service keys exist for apps that are not CF aware, i.e. don't understand VCAP_SERVICES, and non-CF deployed services to consume service on CF (at least that's my understanding). They can be handy for some additional situations like this one, but not the primary purpose. If you use rolling deploys, it won't have this limitation. You could also talk to your service provider about additional functionality to share users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request a static username using the extra [bind parameter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcp-service-broker/blob/b09eb1aa57dec31d217fb0148f227b710fd07338/docs/classes/google-cloudsql-postgres.md#binding) "username":

```
cf bind-service my-app-test-CANDIDATE myapp-test-database -c "{\"username\":\"myuser\"}"
```

With cf7+ it's possible to add parameters to the manifest:

```
applications:
- name: myapp-test
  services:
  - name: myapp-test-database
    parameters: { "username": "myuser" }
```

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#arbitrary-params-binding

> Note: Arbitrary parameters are not supported in app manifests in cf CLI v6.x. **Arbitrary parameters are supported in app manifests in cf CLI v7.0 and later.**

However, I can't find the new syntax here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest-attributes.html#services-block . The syntax I use comes from some other SO question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are strictly doing a `cf push` (or `restart`/`restage`), the broker isn't involved (Cloud Controller doesn't talk to it), and service credentials won't change.

The only action through `cf` commands that can modify your credentials is doing an `unbind` followed by a `bind`. Many, but not all, service brokers will throw away credentials on `unbind` and provide new, unique credentials for a `bind`. This is often desirable so that you can rotate credentials if credentials are compromised.

Where this can be a problem is if you have custom scripts or cf cli plugins to implement rolling deployments. Most tools like this will use two separate application instances, which means you'll have two separate bindings and two separate sets of credentials.

If you must have one set of credentials you can use a service key to work around this. Service keys are like bindings but not associated with an application in CloudFoundry.

The downside of the service key is that it's not automatically exposed to your application, like a binding, through `$VCAP_SERVICES`. To workaround this, you can pass the service key creds into a user-provided service and then bind that to your application, or you can pass them into your application through other environment variables, like `DB_URL`.

The other option is to switch away from using scripts and cf cli plugins for blue/green deployment and to use the support that is now built into Cloud Foundry. With `cf` cli version 7+, `cf push` has a `--strategy` option which can be set to `rolling` to perform a rolling deployment. This does not create multiple application instances and so there would only ever exist one service binding and one set of credentials.